# SELINUX Error: Failed to resolve typeattributeset statement at /var/lib/selinux/targeted/tmp/modules/100/abrt/cil:73

Tags: runtime-error, selinux

On Redhat 8, based on the following SELINUX denial log generated in audit.log (note I have replaced sections of the original log with three dots for the sake of confidentiality):

```
type=AVC msg=audit(...): avc: denied { read} for pid=1 comm="systemd" name="pcsd.service" dev="dm-0" ino=... scontext=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0 tclass=lnk_file permissive=1
```

I tried to generate a custom policy using the following command:

```
sepolicy generate --application -n init /usr/lib/systemd/systemd
```

The above command successfully generated the following files:

```
init.fc init.if init.pp init_selinux.spec init.sh init.te
```

When I try to run `init.sh` it fails with the following error:

```
/usr/sbin/semodule -i init.pp
libsemanage.semanage_direct_install_info: Overriding init module at lower priority 100 with module at priority 400.
Failed to resolve typeattributeset statement at /var/lib/selinux/targeted/tmp/modules/100/abrt/cil:73
/usr/sbin/semodule: Failed!
```

Any thoughts on why I am getting this error?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

The SELinux module storage allows a priority for SELinux modules.

While the default priority used by `semodule` is 400, the priority used in policy-packages is 100.

Using a higher priority, you can override an existing module with a modified module with the same name.

Now, you try to overwrite a module with a higher priority with a lower one.

In your error, `semodule` complains about this problem in the abrt policy package and gives the corresponding Common Intermediate Language line number as a reference.

To get the failing line within the CIL file, locate your abrt.pp file and call the pp compiler to get the CIL code. The pp compiler is in the High-Level Language Infrastructure folder called hll.

e.g.

```
/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/libexec/selinux/hll/pp ./refpolicy/abrt.pp > abrt.txt
```

Now you can check the given line number in the abrt.txt and see which line conflicts with your init.pp.